# Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning. for Subfolders

Tags: typescript, graphql, next.js, tsc, tsconfig

I have a question regarding this error above.
I understand that I need to set     `"experimentalDecorators": true` to ignore this error message when compiling typescript. However, it doesn't seem to work when there are subfolders in the project.

This is the folder structure of my project.

[image: Folder Structure]

There is tsconfig in the root folder and another tsconfig in the subfolder `./graphql/tsconfig.json`

An compiling error is occuring for the following files: `../graphql/modules/Login.ts`, ../graphql/modules/user/LoginInput.ts

As for workaround, I've thought I needed to specify these path as the parameter for

```
include or files
```

configs.

I've been stuck on this for quite some time. Any advice I would appreciate.

BTW, the configs for tsconfig.json under root directory is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "nexus/typescript-language-service" }],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "types"],
    "target": "esnext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/**/*.ts",
    "**/**/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".",
    "types.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the tsconfig.json under graphql directory is this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "files": ["modules/Login.ts", "modules/user/LoginInput.ts"],
  "include": ["modules/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error for the /graphql/modules/Login.ts and /graphql/modules/users/LoginInput.ts

Any advice, I would appreciate